# Better way to parse headers in retrofit?

Tags: android, http-headers, retrofit

Just started implementing Retrofit today. Is there a more efficient way to get a specific header value that may contain duplicate keys? Specifically, I need to get a "Set-Cookie" header containing the sessionid, but my api passes more than one.

**Here is what I hacked up:**

```
Callback<LoginResponse> mLoginCallback = new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void success(LoginResponse loginResponse, Response response) {
        for(Header header : response.getHeaders()){
            Log.d(TAG, "header: " + header.toString());
            if (header.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("set-cookie") 
                && header.getValue().toLowerCase().contains("sessionid") ){

                    saveSessionCookie(header.getValue());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        Log.e(TAG, "RetrofitError: " + retrofitError.getMessage());
        UIUtils.safeToast(mContext, R.string.error_offline);
        mPasswordView.setText("");
        mUserNameView.requestFocus();
        showProgress(false);
    }
};
```